# I want to show different Divs with data if the string starts with E and A and then delete first two letters from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have data coming from a API in Angular.

```
 $scope.alert = alertMessage;
```

If the Alert message starts with E. i want to show div 1

```
<div class= "alert 1">
<p>{{alert}}</p>
</div>
```

IF the Alert message starts with  A i want to show div 2

```
<div class= "alert 2">
<p>{{alert}}</p>
</div>
```

Also i want to trim first two characters in Alert message.

Can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

```html
//If the Alert message starts with E. i want to show div 1
<div class="alert 1" ng-if="alert[0] === 'E'"><!-- show if the first character is E -->
  <p>{{alert.slice(2)}}</p><!-- remove the first two characters -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-show toggles the appearance of the element by adding the CSS display: none style. ng-if, on the other hand, actually removes the element from the DOM when the condition is false and only adds the element back once the condition turns true. Just depends one what your requirements are but you could essentially use either one.

```js
$scope.alert = alertMessage.slice(2);
```

```html
<div class= "alert 1" ng-show="alert.indexOf('E') == 0"><p>{{alert}}</p>
</div>   
<div class= "alert 2" ng-show="alert.indexOf('A') == 0">
  <p>{{alert}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If the 'E' or 'A' appears in the first two characters that are sliced off, this solution would be slicing too soon.  It's unclear from the question as it currently is.

Comment: You should use 3 equal signs in JavaScript value comparisons.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 indexOf only returns numerics, so its not a big issue here.

Comment: @Taplar I agree it is unclear from the question. I am not sure if he wants to evaluate the E and A before or after he trims. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I have used ng-if for two divs like what taplar told.
in case of removing 2 characters i used {{alert.substring(2)}}

This worked .
Thanks Guys for your help.